# Is it possible to use python for web on a typical Apache webserver?

Tags: python, apache

I have a doubt that even having a good panicked on the internet and doing several searches I could not understand well.

I have a host of godaddy which is the default linux hosting (PHP, Apache and MySQL), however, I wanted to start working with python in the same using MySQL, I saw on the internet that it has the possibility to activate an apache module so that It ran python, however all the tutorials are not very explanatory, and I wanted to know how I can simply upload a site made in django for example to a folder of my server to do tests.

Thank you everyone for the attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"WSGI" is the standard interface between web servers and applications. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: Thanks you for your response, it helped me a lot